# Dynamic Linq Select concatenation

Tags: linq, select, dynamic, lambda, new-operator

I have a dynamic select statement thus:

"new(PurchaseOrderID as ID_PK, PContractNo + GoodsSupplier.AssociatedTo.DisplayName as Search_Results)"

As can be seen I wish to concatenate the 'PContractNo' and 'GoodsSupplier.AssociatedTo.DisplayName' fields into one returned field named 'Search_Results'. It is important that these two fields are combined.

However the Linq library complains regarding the '+', which the expression parser brings back as a 'Concat(etc...), which of course cannot be translated into a store expression.

Obviously therefore I would like some help regarding just how i should format the select string in order to do what I want. I've tried many things!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You, Ian Mac

Comment: As stupid as this sounds try putting a + "" + in between your two fields. Maybe brackets around what your concatenating?

Comment: Unfortunately not! I have previously tried the bracket option also, to no avail. Just to confirm I'm not attempting to do something that can't be done with 'standard' LINQ, the following works fine: select new { ID_PK = o.PurchaseOrderID, Search_Results = o.POrderNo + " : " + o.GoodsSupplier.AssociatedTo.DisplayName }

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class like

```
public class A
{
    public String k;
    public String v;

}
```

and use linq to join

```
res = from a in list
select new A
{
  k = a.Key,
  v = String.Concat(a.Key,a.Value)
};
```